# webstorm IDE: program path not specified when running JS script how can I fix this?

Tags: webstorm

I'm trying to run my JavaScript script, however the message keeps on giving me an error saying:

```
Configuration is still incorrect. Do you want to edit it again?
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Will you be so kind and provide some details of what you have got set up there, please? Or should we just guess what you have got there? My remote-mind-reading helm is charging at the moment ...

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error and it was because I did not specify my path to where I installed node.js. In webstorm, go to File -> Settings -> Language&Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM and in the Node interpreter text box, point it to the path of where node.js was installed. For me it was at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't install node.js and npm, you need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to debug js code and you are using a chrome browser, you need to install their [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji) and use "Inspect in WebStorm" action.

Answer (score 0):

Found the above behavior occurs with the WebStorm project folder within the OneDrive path (Windows 10). As shown in the image of the run configuration, WebStorm shows and error for location of the path to the JavaScript file even though it is correct. Click Run >  Continue from here and it executes with node.js as expected. Move the project to a folder outside of the OneDrive path and the error is gone.

[Image: Webstorm Run Configuration Error in OneDrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROJHd.png)